# Using Stride in Map<Quaternion>

Tags: c++, eigen

I would like to define a Quaternion on top of the memory of an existing matrix. Let this matrix be

```cpp
MatrixXd M(4,4);
```

as an example. I would like my quaternion to be mapped on the second column. Usually I would do

```cpp
Map<Quaterniond> q (&M(0,1));
```

Should M be column-major, this would work since the `Map` would be column-wise.

Now imagine I have a second array N, which is now row-major

```cpp
Matrix<double, -1, -1, RowMajor> N(4,4);
```

Now my mapped quaternion

```cpp
Map<Quaterniond> q (&N(0,1));
```

would be wrong: the elements of `q` would be picked up from N row-wise, that is, `N(0,1),N(0,2),N(0,3),N(1,0)`.

With vectors, I have the possibility of specifying the `Stride`, e.g. the following two lines produce valid results if what I want is to map a 4x1 vector on the second columns of M and N, be them row- or col- major:

```cpp
Map<const VectorXs, 0, Stride<-1, -1> > vc(&M(0,1), 4, 1, Stride<-1, -1>(M.colStride(),M.rowStride()));
Map<const VectorXs, 0, Stride<-1, -1> > vr(&N(0,1), 4, 1, Stride<-1, -1>(N.colStride(),N.rowStride()));
```

I have attempted to use the `Stride` technique to `Map<Quaternion>` without success. In fact, from the [eigen documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Map_3_01Quaternion_3_01__Scalar_01_4_00_01__Options_01_4.html), it seems this is not possible.

The questions are:

1. Is it possible to use `Stride` in `Map<Quaternion>`? How?
2. If not, why is this not possible?
3. What workaround or alternative do I have, apart from copying the data to a new `Quaternion` object?

Comment: This is indeed not possible, but I would really recommend to just to copy back-and-forth any quaternions to the corresponding row/column of `M`. You don't really gain a lot using a `Map` in this case. If you really need this, you need to make a feature request.

Comment: Nice answer chtz. Thanks. -- I dont know why I cannot vote up.

Comment: @chtz that should be an answer - an accepted one, to be specific :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, this is not possible. This would probably not be too hard to implement, I added a short comment on a [related feature request](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=1129), which would directly allow to write `N.row(i).asQuaternion()`.

At the moment, you can just copy back and forth between the matrix and the quaternion, which is usually very cheap, maybe even cheaper than handling a pointer and a stride object would be:

```
Eigen::Matrix4Xd M; // input/output matrix
// extract quaternion from M
Eigen::Quaterniond q(M.row(1).transpose());

// ... do something with q

// copy back quaternion
M.row(1) = q.coeffs().transpose(); // transposing not necessary (would be done implicitly)
```

If `M` does not have 4 columns at compile time, you may need an intermediate `Eigen::Vector4d` object, or copy the row into an existing `Eigen::Quaterniond` object, i.e., these alternatives work in this case (copying back stays the same):

```
// If M.row(1) is not known at compile time to have 4 elements:
Eigen::Quaterniond q(Eigen::Vector4d(M.row(1)));

q.coeffs() = M.row(1); // copy row into an existing quaternion
```

Comment: Thanks again chtz. Indeed when using matrices larger than 4 elements I also had to use intermediate Eigen vectors before being able to construct the quaternion.

This was so even if instead of using `col(i)` I was using `M.block<4,1>(0,1)`, which is a 4x1 vector expression. 

So this worked as you say,

      Eigen::Quaterniond q(Eigen::Vector4d(M.col(1).head(4)));

But these did not


      Eigen::Quaterniond q(M.block<4,1>(0,1));
      Eigen::Quaterniond q(M.block(4,1,0,1));
      Eigen::Quaterniond q(M.col(1).head(4));

Comment: `M.block<4,1>(0,1).transpose()` should work as well. And/but this also works if `M` has more than 4 columns.

Comment: chtz your answer is accurate, but for the benefit of others, I must say that you took my example as the problem of assigning a quaternion on a ROW of a given matrix (the issue appearing with column-major matrices), whereas I was asking on how to do it for COLUMNS (the issue appearing for row-major matrices). The problems are dual of course, but people reading your answer might get confused.